# Expected value of biggest distance of adjacent points uniformly picked in $[0,1]$

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, expectation

We pick $n\ge 2$ points in $[0,1]$ with uniform distribution. What is the expected value of the largest distance of $2$ adjacent points?

Comment: Isn't this closely related to the expected value of the biggest of $n$ numbers picked uniformly from $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The expected value is asymptotic to $(\log n)/n$ as $n$ tends to infinity (By "asymptotic" I mean that the ratio tends to 1). One way to see this is to use the representation of order statistics of uniform points as the first $n$ points of a Poisson process, normalized by the $n+1$ Point. Since the sum of $n+1$ exponential variables is concentrated, the question reduces to the distribution of the maximum of $n-1$ Exponential variables.

Usually one considers the maximum $M_n$ of the $n+1$ gaps including the gap between zero and the first point and between 1 and the last point, but that does not change the asymptotics. The known properties of $M_n$ are surveyed in the introduction of Devroye's paper that Brendan McKay mentioned:
https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176994313

In particular the fact about Poisson processes I noted  above is Lemma 2.1 there, and lemmas 2.4, 2.5 and 2.6 describe more precise asymptotics for the maximal gap.

Comment: Isn't there also a constant (namely Euler's constant)?  See Lemma 2.6 of https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2243743.pdf?casa_token=I9YOl9sJKMsAAAAA:RYP0Kz5Fc8S1PRioq1fiubGMkxn4fpc40FG8BnGX_pW6TU9Hcolh8hcOXo3fdJtMNYydjsf1_tdD-vb-PWQV5o1hJPRynDZypLrXohzpo8J41gbJWcM

Comment: Brendan, that constant only appears in the second order term.

Comment: Oops, yes indeed.